# Code structure for simple live jquery form validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am learning javascript and jquery and I have written the following code to check if some inputs of my form are filled, if they are they get a special styling.

The code works fine, but I'm wondering what's the best way to write this, maybe if it can be shorter?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id_email").change(function () {
        var emailField = document.getElementById("id_email").value;
        
        if (emailField.indexOf("@") >= 0 && emailField.indexOf(".") >= 0) {
            $(this).attr( /* styling my field */ );
        } else {
            $(this).attr( /* styling my field */ );
        }
    });
    
    $("#id_last_name").change(function () {
        var nameField = document.getElementById("id_last_name").value;
        
        if (nameField.length > 0) {
            $(this).attr( /* styling if true */ );
        } else {
            $(this).attr( /* styling if false */ );
        }
    });
    
    $("#id_phone").change(function () {
        var phoneField = document.getElementById("id_phone").value;
        
        if (phoneField.length > 0) {
            $(this).attr( /* styling if true */ );
        } else {
            $(this).attr( /* styling if false */ );
        }
    });
    
    $("#id_company").change(function () {
        var companyField = document.getElementById("id_company").value;
        
        if (companyField.length > 0) {
            $(this).attr( /* styling if true */ );
        } else {
            $(this).attr( /* styling if false */ );
        }
    });
    
    $("#id_activity").change(function () {
        var activityField = document.getElementById("id_activity").value;
        
        if (activityField !== "---------") {
            $(this).attr( /* styling if true */ );
        } else {
            $(this).attr( /* styling if false */ );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shorthand if statements and use `$(this).val()` instead of `document.getElementById("").value;`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id_email").change(function() {
    var emailField = $(this).val();
    (emailField.indexOf("@") >= 0 && emailField.indexOf(".") >= 0) ? $(this).attr( /* styling my field */ ) : $(this).attr( /* styling my field */ );
  });

  $("#id_last_name").change(function() {
    var nameField = $(this).val();
    (nameField.length > 0) ? $(this).attr( /* styling if true */ ) : $(this).attr( /* styling if false */ );
  });

  $("#id_phone").change(function() {
    var phoneField = $(this).val();
    (phoneField.length > 0) ? $(this).attr( /* styling if true */ ) : $(this).attr( /* styling if false */ );
  });

  $("#id_company").change(function() {
    var companyField = $(this).val();
    (companyField.length > 0) ? $(this).attr( /* styling if true */ ) : $(this).attr( /* styling if false */ );
  });

  $("#id_activity").change(function() {
    var activityField = $(this).val();
    (activityField !== "---------") ? $(this).attr( /* styling if true */ ) : $(this).attr( /* styling if false */ );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in case you have the same styles for the inputs.

```
  function stylingMyInput(element, type) {
    if (type === true) {
      element.attr( /* styling if true */ );
    } else {
      element.attr( /* styling if false */ );
    }

  }


  $("#id_email").change(function() {
    var emailField = document.getElementById("id_email").value;
    stylingMyInput(emailField, emailField.indexOf("@") >= 0 && emailField.indexOf(".") >= 0)
  });

  $("#id_last_name").change(function() {
    var nameField = document.getElementById("id_last_name").value;

    stylingMyInput(nameField,nameField.length > 0)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give all the input elements you want to check a common class (say, `input_field`) and then attach the `change` event to those elements at once.  Then in the event handler, check your elements and apply styling as needed:

```
$('.input_field').change(function(){
  if( (this.id=='id_email' && !validEmail(this.value))
      || (this.id=='id_last_name' && this.value.length == 0)
      || (this.id=='id_phone' && this.value.length == 0)
    ){    
      $(this).addClass('invalid');
      $(this).removeClass('valid');
  }
  else{
      $(this).addClass('valid');
      $(this).removeClass('invalid');
  }         
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jerrade/2k0fw8tL/1/)